# Having trouble with modular arithmatic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is the first in a series of problems I am working through and I feel if I can get some help in walking through this I can get through the others. Prove $a^2 \equiv  c^2 \: (\textrm{mod} \: n)$

I think there is something with this implying that $ab \equiv cd  \:(\textrm{mod} \: n)$ but not sure how to treat the modulos.

Edit: yes, sorry I did not provide all of the info. a, b, c, d, and n are integers and $n >1$ and $a \equiv c (\textrm{mod} \: n)$ and $b \equiv d (\textrm{mod} \: n)$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  $a^2\equiv c^2\pmod n$ means $n$ divides $a^2-c^2$, which is not always true

Comment: So are you saying I cannot prove that expression?

Comment: thaneofcawdorIf,  $a≡c\mod n$, you can square both sides and get $a^2≡c^2\mod n$, in both cases $n|(a-c)$

Comment: Not without further information about $a$ and $c$; for example $1^2\not\equiv2^2\pmod5$ though $1\times1\equiv2\times3\pmod5$

Comment: Also note:  $2^2\equiv3^2\pmod5$ though $5$ doesn’t divide $3-2$

Comment: $a\equiv c\bmod n\implies c-a=kn\implies c^2-a^2=k'n\implies a^2\equiv c^2\bmod n$.

Comment: I suggest, thane, that you puzzle through the above, and when you understand how to fill in the justifications, post it as an answer.

Comment: Any thoughts, thane, on the replies you have had over the last two days?

Comment: Care to engage with us, thane?

Answer (score 0):

If $a\equiv c \mod n$ and $b\equiv d \mod n$, then $ab\equiv cd \mod n$.

Proof: We have $a=c+kn$ and $b=d+rn$ for certain integers $k,r$.
Then, $$ab=(c+kn)(d+rn)=cd+n(cr+kd+krn).$$ So, $$ab=cd+n\alpha,$$
where $\alpha=cr+kd+krn$ is an integer. This proves that $ab\equiv cd \mod n$.

Now, what happens if you choose $a=b, c=d$?